# Why is sequence $(1+\frac{1}{n})^{n+1}$ descending?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits, exponential-function

I was studying the proof of $e$ number when I noticed something:

Why is the sequence $(1+\frac{1}{n})^{n+1}$ descending? It starts ascending with grater n but in one moment it starts descending? Why is that? On what $n$ this happens?

Edit:
Let me try to rephrase the question...
How come  that sequence $(1+\frac{1}{n})^n$ rises, but the sequence $(1+\frac{1}{n})^{n+1}$  falls, just because of the one more 1+1/n multiplication (power)?

Comment: See [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/121076/proving-1-1-nn1-gt-e/121095#121095).

Comment: I edited the question with more details