# proving montonity and convergence of sequence en = (1 + 1/n)^n

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Prove the following. What would be the summation formula be for the first part?

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by 'summation formula' ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [Binomial Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_theorem#Statement_of_the_theorem), we have

$$\begin{align}
e_n&=\left(1+\frac1n\right)^n\\\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}{k}\left(\frac1n\right)^k\\\\
&=1+n\left(\frac1n\right)+\frac{n(n-1)}{2!}\left(\frac1n\right)^2+\cdots+\frac{(n)(n-1)(n-2)\cdots(n-(n-1))}{n!}\left(\frac1n\right)^n\\\\
&=1+1+\frac1{2!}\left(1-\frac1n\right)+\frac1{3!}\left(1-\frac1n\right)\left(1-\frac2n\right)\\\\
&+\cdots+\frac1{n!}\left(1-\frac1n\right)\left(1-\frac2n\right)\cdots\left(1-\frac{n-1}n\right) \tag 1
\end{align}$$

as was to be shown!

---

To show that $e_n$ is increasing we will show that $\frac{e_{n+1}}{e_n}\ge 1$.  To that end, we write

$$\begin{align}
\frac{e_{n+1}}{e_n}&=\frac{\left(1+\frac{1}{n+1}\right)^{n+1}}{\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^n}\\\\
&=\left(\frac{n(n+2)}{(n+1)^2}\right)^{n+1}\left(1+\frac1n\right)\\\\
&=\left(1-\frac{1}{(n+1)^2}\right)^{n+1}\left(1+\frac1n\right) \tag 2\\\\
&\ge\left(1-\frac{1}{n+1}\right)\left(1+\frac1n\right) \tag 3\\\\
&=1
\end{align}$$

where in going from $(2)$ to $(3)$, we used [Bernoulli's Inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli%27s_inequality).  Thus, $e_n$ in monotonically increasing; and we are done!

---

From $(1)$ is trivial to see that $e_n\ge 2$ for $n\ge 1$.

Noting that all of the parenthetical terms are less than $1$, and $n!>2^{n-1}$ for $n\ge2$, then for $n\ge 2$, we have

$$e_n\le 1+1+\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{2^k}=3$$

Thus, we conclude that $e_n$ is a monotonically increasing sequence that is bounded above by $3$.  Therefore, $e_n$ converges to some real number betweem $2$ and $3$.  And we are done!

Comment: This looks [eerily familiar](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/306245)... and very similar to what I was about to post.

Comment: @robjohn Or [even more eerily](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1452820/the-sequence-a-n-left-fracnn1-rightn1-is-increasing/1452882#1452882).  Great minds think alike.  Well, yours might be great.  ;-))

Comment: That is the other direction (also shown in the linked answer). Glad to see Bernoulli's Inequality being used.

Comment: @robjohn Yes. I've used that little inequality a number of times to answer questions on MSE.

Comment: Thanks alot. This was indeed very helpful :)

Comment: You're welcome.  My pleasure.

Answer (score 2):

To prove (a) and (b) use the binomial theorem. To prove (c) use the hint, that is, bound $e_n$ above by a geometric progression with ratio $1/2$.

Comment: And just how does one show from the binomial theorem that $e_n$ monotonically increases?

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Binomial theorem and

$$1-\frac{k}{n+1} > 1-\frac{k}{n}$$