# Evaluating $\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{x}{2^x-1}$ without using L'Hôspital's rule

Tags: limits, limits-without-lhopital

So lately, when one my friends had asked for help, he showed me this task:

> Evaluate the following limit $$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{x}{2^x-1}$$

The problem is that one is not ought to use L'Hôspital's rule (which yields $\frac{1}{\ln 2}$), because derivatives weren't even introduced yet.

I am sorry that I can't see a way to change this term algebraically and it would be a pleasure if you helped me.

Comment: Well, if we're not going to do this with derivatives (it's rather immediate that the answer has to be $\frac1{\ln 2}$, just from the definition of the derivative applied to $2^x$ at $x = 0$), then we need to know more about the nitty-gritty details. How have you defined the natural logarithm? How have you defined $2^x$?

Comment: $\ln(x)=\log_e(x)$

Comment: That's not a definition. At least not the kind I'm after. If you see something like $\ln(2)$, what does that _mean_ to you? What property does that number have? In other words, I want you to finish the sentence "$\ln 2$ is the unique number such that ..." And "$\ln 2$ is the unique number that is equal to $\log_e(2)$" just isn't going to help me help you figure this out. Also, I would like you to do the same with $2^x$. Mathematical proofs begin and end with _definitions_, so you need to have those clear in your mind to get _anywhere_.

Comment: Another try: $\ln 2$ is the unique number such that $e^{\ln 2}=2$.

Comment: That's a _lot_ better. I can play the game again with $e^x$, but we have to stop at some point. Now what about $2^x$?

Comment: Let $2^x:=\lim_{n\to\infty}2^{q_n}$ if ($q_n$) is a sequence of rational numbers and $\lim_{n\to\infty}q_n=x$.

Comment: The definition of $2^x$ which you mention is the most difficult one. A full development of the theory of exponential and logarithmic functions based on this approach is presented in my post: https://paramanands.blogspot.com/2014/05/theories-of-exponential-and-logarithmic-functions-part-3.html?m=0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since we are not allowed to use derivative we need to start from some well grounded point.

Usually the starting point is the following limit for sequences (wich can be [proved by monotonicity theorem](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1482253/505767)):

$$\lim_{n\to \infty}\left(1+\frac1n\right)^n =e$$

which can be easily extended to real functions

$$\lim_{y\to \infty}\left(1+\frac1y\right)^y =e$$

From the latter by $z=\frac1y \to 0$ we easily obtain that

$$\lim_{y\to \infty}\left(1+\frac1y\right)^y =\lim_{z\to 0}\left(1+z\right)^\frac1z=e \implies \lim_{z\to 0}\frac{\log(1+z)}{z}=1$$

and finally by $y=e^x-1 \to 0$ with $x\to 0$

$$\lim_{z\to 0}\frac{\log(1+z)}{z}=1 \implies \lim_{x\to 0}\frac x{e^x-1}=1$$

and then

$$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{x}{2^x-1}=\lim_{x\to 0}\;\frac1{\log 2}\cdot\frac{x\log 2}{e^{x\log 2}-1}=\frac1{\log 2}\cdot\cdot 1 =\frac1{\log 2}$$

Comment: OK, thanks for the answer, but it still bugs me how this can be in a German High School text book in Year 11.

Comment: @FelixGelbh Usually the notation $\log 2$ isalso  used for $\ln$. I can't explain why. Of course it can be obbained without derivatives but we need to start from some no trivial result.

Comment: Excuse me, but can you explain how $\frac{x\log 2}{e^{x\log 2}-1}=\frac{x}{e^x-1}$? @gimusi

Comment: @FelixGelbh Just take as a new variable $y=x\log 2 \to 0$ then $$\frac{x\log 2}{e^{x\log 2}-1}=\frac{y}{e^y-1} \to 1$$

Answer (score 5):

**One way**

Apply definition of derivative of $2^x$
$$\Longrightarrow \lim_{x\to 0} \frac{2^x-2^0}{x-0}$$
$$=\frac{d}{dx}(2^x)|_0$$
$$=2^0\log 2$$
$$\Longrightarrow \lim_{x\to 0}\frac{x}{2^x-1}=\frac{1}{\log 2}$$

**Second way**

Apply change of variable, let $2^x=y$
$$\Longrightarrow x=\frac{\log y}{\log 2}$$
Also, as $x\rightarrow 0, y\rightarrow 1$. So, required limit
$$=\lim_{y\to 1}\frac{\frac{\log y}{\log 2}}{y-1}$$
$$=\lim_{y\to 1}\frac{\log y}{\log 2 \times (y-1)}$$
Now, apply the well-known fact that $\forall y>0$
$$\frac{y-1}{y}\leq\log y\leq y-1$$
Now, divide both sides by $y-1$ and apply sandwich theorem as $y\rightarrow 1$.

Comment: You should clarify how the last inequality can be derived.

Comment: Well, I assumed that OP knows some basic properties of logarithms. Proofs without using derivatives can be found at https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Bounds_of_Natural_Logarithm

Comment: That's fine but in that case you should specify what kind of derivation you are referring to and possibly give the reference. Thanks for your clarification.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that you know that $(2^x)'=\log(2)\times2^x$, then, in particular, you know that$$\lim_{x\to0}\frac{2^x-1}x=\log(2).$$Therefore,$$\lim_{x\to0}\frac x{2^x-1}=\frac1{\log(2)}.$$

Comment: Yeah, but didn't you use L'Hôspital's rule?

Comment: I most definitely did **not** use it. I just used the fact that $(a^x)'=\log(a)a^x$ and, in particular, that the derivative of $a^x$ at $0$ is $\log(a)$.

Comment: “because derivatives weren't even introduced yet”

Comment: @gimusi That's a good point. On the other hand, the accepted answer uses derivatives.

Comment: Not in the second way.

Comment: I doubt that$$y>0\implies\frac{y-1}y\leqslant\log(y)\leqslant y-1$$can be proved without using derivatives.

Comment: That's also a good point to discuss for the benefit of the OP.

Answer (score 1):

As $a=e^{\ln a}$ for $a>0$

$$\lim_{x\to0}\dfrac{a^x-1}x=\ln a\cdot\lim_{x\to0}\dfrac{e^{x\ln a}-1}{x\ln a}=?$$

Answer (score 1):

Is your friend allowed to use/familiar with derivatives to begin with?

We have
$$\displaystyle\lim_{x\to 0}{1\over {2^x - 2^0\over x-0}} = {1\over f’(0)}$$ where $f(x) = 2^x$, so the limit is $\frac 1{ln2}$.

Comment: No, they haven't been even introduced yet.

Comment: Okay. Is he familiar with the fact that for continuous $f(x)$ and $\lim g = L$, $\lim f(g) = f(L)$? (Limits in continuous functions are commutative/transitive)

Comment: Yes, but this function is not defined if $x=0$, isn't it?

Comment: Evaluating such an indeterminate expression is the whole point of limits (or at least in some ways) @FelixGelbh

Comment: “because derivatives weren't even introduced yet”