# Proving inequality $(1-1/n)^{n - 1/2} < 1/e$

Tags: real-analysis, limits, inequality

I would like to [prove](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=(1-1%2Fn)%5E(n%20-%201%2F2)%20%20for%20n%3D%5B1,2,3,4,5,6%5D)
$$(1-1/n)^{n \;-\; 1/2} < 1/e$$
where  $n \geq 2$.

I saw the post [Proving $(1 + 1/n)^{n+1} \gt e$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/121076), but it is not the same, and [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1841922) (which is close to my question) involves some theorems I don't know.

I tried to take $\;\ln\;$ of both sides:
$$g(n) := (n - 1/2) \ln(1-1/n)   <  -1$$
Proving that $g$ is increasing (by computing $g'$) seems difficult and painful. Proving that $g(n) \to -1$ when $n \to\infty$ shouldn't be hard, however.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Proof via differentiation is feasible. Put, for all $t>1$ :

$$u(t)=\left(t-\frac12\right)\ln \left(1-\frac1t\right)$$

Then :

$$u'(t)=\ln\left(1-\frac1t\right)+\left(t-\frac12\right)\frac{\frac1{t^2}}{1-\frac1t}=\ln\left(1-\frac1t\right)+\frac{t-\frac12}{t^2-t}$$

$$u''(t)=\frac1{t^2-t}+\frac{t^2-t-(2t-1)(t-\frac12)}{(t^2-t)^2}=\frac{-1}{2(t^2-t)^2}<0$$

Hence $u'$ is decreasing. But $\displaystyle{\lim_{+\infty}u'=0}$ and so $u'>0$, so that $u$ is increasing. Finally, since $\displaystyle{\lim_{+\infty}u}=-1$, we conclude that $\forall t>1,u(t)<-1$, hence :

> $$\boxed{\forall t>1,\left(1-\frac1t\right)^{t-1/2}<\frac1e}$$

Comment: @Alphonse: Sorry, there was a bug in my computation. Not it should be ok.

Answer (score 1):

It can be seen as a consequence of the [Hermite-Hadamard inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hermite%E2%80%93Hadamard_inequality), or just convexity.

$$-\left(n-\frac{1}{2}\right)\log\left(1-\frac{1}{n}\right) = \left(n-\frac{1}{2}\right)\int_{n-1}^{n}\frac{dx}{x}=\left(n-\frac{1}{2}\right)\int_{-1/2}^{1/2}\frac{dx}{\left(n-\frac{1}{2}\right)+x} $$
can be written as
$$ \int_{-1/2}^{1/2}\frac{dx}{1+\frac{x}{2n-1}} = 2\int_{0}^{1/2}\frac{dx}{1-\left(\frac{x}{2n-1}\right)^2}> 2\int_{0}^{1/2}\,dx=1$$
hence by exponentiation
$$ \left(1-\frac{1}{n}\right)^{n-1/2}<\frac{1}{e}$$
follows.